# Load balance jboss fuse service works

Tags: apache-camel, jboss-eap-6, jbossfuse, fuseesb, switchyard

Hi have a scenario where I to develop a switch yard application  to poll a database every 5 seconds.i have two instances of jboss eap running and the source application is only one database.is there any way to load balance between both the eap servers.

Do I need to create the jboss servers in clusters?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running two standalone EAP containers you can  bring in hardware load balancer like F5 to balance the requests. The algorithm for routing can be configured in F5